# I have imported org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions but still throwing error Actions can not resolved to a variable

Tags: java, selenium

Showing Actions can not be resolved to a variable.

I am working on Mouse movement and creating object of Actions class.I have already imported org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions. But still the error exist.I have tried following options:

1.Restart,
2.Close and open project
3.Refresh
4.Clean

Please help me into this

```
package storeFront;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class WithTestNG {


@Test(priority = 0)
        public void OpenStore() {
    String exePath = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" );
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            String URL = "https://facebook.com";

            driver.get(URL);

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("a#top-bar-menu.search-dropdown.ng-binding")).build().perform();
        }
```

Comment: I am curious how did you manage without importing `WebDriver` and `ChromeDriver`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [selenium-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/3.141.59) library to your project [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) in order to be able to use [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class.

I would strongly recommend using a build system like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) which provides automatic [dependencies management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html) so you could declare `selenium-java` and `testng` as your project dependencies and the remaining ones would be automatically resolved by Maven or Gradle.

[image]

Example Maven [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-selenium-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Check out [Selenium with Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+with+Java) article for comprehensive information and example project which you can use as the reference or skeleton for your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);
```

instead of:

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("a#top-bar-menu.search-dropdown.ng-binding")).build().perform();
```